# What is the difference between $root and $parent?

Tags: knockout.js

I am learning KnockoutJS, but I do not understand the difference between `$root` and `$parent` usage. Please see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/2gt4K/27/), or the below code:

```html
<div data-bind="foreach:mainloop">
    $data Value: <span data-bind="text:$data.firstName"></span> 
                  <span data-bind="text:$data.lastName"></span> --(1)

    <br/>
    $parent Value: <span data-bind="text:firstName"> </span> 
                   <span data-bind="text:$parent.lastName"></span>
    <br/>
    $root Value: <span data-bind="text:firstName"></span>
                 <span data-bind="text:$root.lastName"></span>
    <br/>
        <hr/>
</div>
```

```javascript
var mainLoopModel = function () {
    var self = this; // Root Level scope
    self.mainloop = ko.observableArray([{
        'firstName': 'jhon'
    }, {
        'firstName': 'sam'
    }]);
    self.lastName = ko.observable('peters');
    /*if you remove $data before lastName in note (1) you get undefined error because because mainloop dont have lastName root model has lastName so you have to access using parent or higher level */
}

ko.applyBindings(new mainLoopModel());
```

In the above code `$root` and `$parent` are both used for the same purpose: to refer outer scope variable. I just like to know is there any difference between the `$root` and `$parent` usages? If yes then please help me understand with a good example for correct usage.

Comment: You can have multiple levels of parents/ancestors (e.g. a `foreach` inside a `foreach`). `$parent` is the *immediate parent*, `$root` is the *outermost parent*.

Comment: The knockout documentation is quite good, please read the relevant section: Binding context http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Answer (score 62, accepted):

They are similar but different:

- `$root` refers to the view model applied to the DOM with `ko.applyBindings`;
- `$parent` refers to the immediate outer scope;

Or, visually, from `$data`'s perspective:

[image: tree visualization]

Or, in words of [the relevant documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html):

> - `$parent`: This is the view model object in the parent context, the one immeditely outside the current context.
> - `$root`: This is the main view model object in the root context, i.e., the topmost parent context. It’s usually the object that was passed to `ko.applyBindings`. It is equivalent to `$parents[$parents.length - 1]`.
> - `$data`: This is the view model object in the current context. In the root context, $data and $root are equivalent.

**You'll only see a practical difference if you have view models nested more than one level, otherwise they will amount to the same thing.**

It benefit is rather simple to demonstrate:

```js
var Person = function(name) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = ko.observable(name);
  self.children = ko.observableArray([]);
}
  
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.name = 'root view model';
  self.mainPerson = ko.observable();
}

var vm = new ViewModel(),
    grandpa = new Person('grandpa'),
    daddy = new Person('daddy'),
    son1 = new Person('marc'),
    son2 = new Person('john');

vm.mainPerson(grandpa);
grandpa.children.push(daddy);
daddy.children.push(son1);
daddy.children.push(son2);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
th, td { padding: 10px; border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="person">
  <tr>
    <td data-bind="text: $root.name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $parent.name"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: $data.name"></td>
  </tr>
  <!-- ko template: { name: 'person', foreach: children } --><!-- /ko -->
</script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>$root</th>
    <th>$parent</th>
    <th>$data</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- ko template: { name: 'person', data: mainPerson } --><!-- /ko -->
</table>
```

The `$root` is always the same. The `$parent` is different, depending on how deeply nested you are.