# Knockout JS foreach $root undefined

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to create a radio group in Knockout JS, here is the template code

```
<p>Selected Plan <div data-bind="text: selectedPlan"></div></p>
<div data-bind="foreach: plans">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="plan" data-bind="attr: {value: id}, checked: $root.selectedPlan"/>
        <span data-bind="html: title"></span>
        <div data-bind="text: desc"></div>
    </label>
</div>
```

In the component `selectePlan` and `plans` are registered as follows

```
this.plans = ko.observableArray([/* array of plans */]);
this.selectedPlan = ko.observable('xxxxx');
```

I have verified that `xxxxx` is a valid entry in `this.plans`. Despite this an error is raised in the console

> knockout.js:3391 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding
>   "foreach: function(){return plans }" Message: Unable to process
>   binding "checked: function(){return $root.selectedPlan }" Message:
>   Cannot read property 'selectedPlan' of undefined

It seems the `$root` keyword is `undefined` for some reason...

EDIT:
Structure of plans

```
[{
 id: 'xxxxx',
 desc: 'This is a great plan',
 title: '<strong>Save with great plan</strong>',
},
...
]
```

Comment: `this.plans = ko.observableArray([/* array of plans */]);` what is the structure of `plans`? It seems you do not need to use $root at all since you have `foreach` ... Are they just strings?

Comment: @Akrion Don't I need `$root` to get access to the component proper (and know current selection) so only the correct input is selected? BTW - added structure of `plans` to the question

Comment: @quickshiftin please glance upon my answer as I think it might solve your inquiry, instead of the provided albeit valid, workaround as accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<p>Selected Plan
  <b><span data-bind="text: selectedPlan"></span></b>
</p>
<div data-bind="foreach: plans">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="plan" data-bind="value: title, checked: $parent.selectedPlan"/>
    <span data-bind="html: title"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: desc"></span>
  </label>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var viewModel = {
    plans: ko.observableArray([
      {id: 1, desc: 'Red Foo', title: 'Foo'}, 
      {id: 2, desc: 'Blue Bas', title: 'Bas'}
    ]),
    selectedPlan: ko.observable()
  };
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

Few changes I made:

1. Did not use `attr` binding and did instead straight `value` and `checked`
2. I used `$parent` to get to the top level but `$root` works as well
3. I changed the html a little bit to get it on one line etc.

Comment: I also have a similar working example on codepen, but in my real project `$root` is `undefined`. Trying to figure out how I can debug it, beyond printing out the value atop the loop...

Comment: What about $parent? What does that point to?  Also what do you get in Dev tools when you select the element and do ‘ko.dataFor($0)’???

Comment: Switching to `$parent` did the trick. I also found this [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286027/what-is-the-difference-between-root-and-parent) helpful. Appreciate your help @Akrion!

Answer (score 2):

I know this has been answered, but I'm thinking you're still wondering why $root is undefined(I would). I can see you're talking about a 'component' here and there. Might it be as simple as you just trying to get the root of the component, thus `$component`?

from the knockout site:

> $component
>
> If you’re within the context of a particular component template, then
>   $component refers to the viewmodel for that component. It’s the
>   component-specific equivalent to $root. In the case of nested
>   components, $component refers to the viewmodel for the closest
>   component.
>
> This is useful, for example, if a component’s template includes one or
>   more foreach blocks in which you wish to refer to some property or
>   function on the component viewmodel rather than on the current data
>   item.

Please view the [Knockout Binding Context](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) page for more info.

Comment: Thanks for this submission @Sam! I have actually moved on from the task which brought me to this question, so I'm unsure I'll be able to validate it (upvote though!)